# Posting JSON via JQuery to a Spring Roo Controller

Tags: jquery, json

I recently ran into an issue using JQuery and Spring Roo. I wanted to post data to a JSON enabled URL of a Spring Roo controller (I don't think this is especially important, but I put it out there just for clarity's sake). I knew that the controller worked fine because I could post data to it via Curl command, like this:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8080/PeopleProject/people 
     -d '{"firstName":"some","lastName":"guy","email":"some@guy.com"}
```

So, then I tried posting data from a $.post() call in Javascript, like this:

```
 var data = {"firstName":"some","lastName":"guy","email":"some.guy@gmail.com"};
 $.post('/PeopleProject/people', data, successfulPost ) ;
```

However, I would get errors on the server side about not being able to parse the input. Running the debugger, I could see that the data being posted via this Javascript was coming across URL encoded, whereas the data from the curl command was not.

Finally, after much messing around, I tried this Javascript:

```
 var jqxhr =
            $.ajax({
                url: "/PeopleProject/people",
                processData : true,
                contentType:"application/json",
                type : "POST",
                data: '{"firstName":"some","lastName":"guy","email":"some.guy@gmail.com"}',
            })
```

And this worked! But, I am not sure why it worked and the $.post() did not. Can anyone more knowledgeable than me about Javascript/JQuery explain this?

I thought I read somewhere that a JSON post to a server would encode stuff as name value pairs, but I am guessing this isn't right since I have seen that a the curl command posted nice, clean JSON, while the $.post() pushed a URL encoded query string.

So my question is: is the above ajax() call the preferred method for pushing JSON data to a server? Or, is there a way to use $.push() and get it work?

Answer (score 1):

`$.post` does not support `processData` as an argument. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
jQuery.post( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] )
```

**Update**

`processData: false` tells jquery to leave the data parameter as-is (in this case as a json string) and send it as the request body. Since `$.post` doesn't have an option to disable `processData`, you can't do it with `$.post` without first using `$.ajaxSetup({processData: false, contentType: "application/json"});`

Comment: Thanks, yes, I did know that. But the default is "true" anyway, so I was thinking that this isn't the main difference. It seems like the contentType is the big difference.  I'll have to try taking that out and seeing if it still works.

Comment: You also have a syntax error in the way you used `processData: false` within `$.post`. If it would have been an acceptable argument, it would have simply been `true` or `false` without a label, or it would be part of an object such as `{ processData: false }`

Comment: Oops, sorry and thanks! Actually that was a mistake and I've edited the original post to remove that. I was working on this for about 8 hours yesterday and trying lots of different things.  That `processData:false` did not work for `$.post()`, as you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that the $.post() automatically encodes data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. By switching over to the $.ajax() call you have the ability to select the encoding, which is clearly implied by my experience.  Thanks everyone!